# problem with downloading csv file through HTTP header

Tags: php, mysql, file, http-headers

so attempted this:

```
header("Content-type: application/csv");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=file.csv");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");
echo $fields;
```

tried also and many others.

```
header("Content-type: text/csv");
```

what happens however is, the MySQL data simply echos out to the browser.

this is the HTTPheaderResponse i grabbed with firebug:

```
Date    Wed, 18 May 2011 14:15:18 GMT
X-Powered-By    PHP/5.1.6
Content-disposition attachment;filename=MyVerySpecial.csv
Connection  close
Content-Length  992
Server  Apache/2.2.3 (Red Hat)
```

**EDIT:** note it is a return from a JQuery .post() I am trying this, if that affects it.

so, does anyone know why this issue may be occuring? I am at a loss.

thanks

Comment: do you have any output before headers? your code is okay and should work

Comment: well, if look at my latest edit, I am attempting this as the return of a JQuery .post(), if that may be affecting it?

Comment: it should be just a link. Why do you need jquery.post?

Comment: well its an extra feature off a page, and so I am querying the database to go into the file, without refreshing the page.

Comment: lol.  Uh yeah, that would have been important information to have.  : )  Your best bet is to use an actual form and do a traditional post... which can be done to an iFrame to maintain AJAX-like behavior.

Comment: Or, if you can, just make it a GET request depending on how much/what kinds of data you need to stuff through.

Comment: make `ajax` call and return link where file may be downloaded (or construct it in `success` function). Then, put it as src of `img`. I doubt it is possible to download file the way you want it.

Comment: ye, ive just gone about it that way now, create the file, return the link.

Comment: i was more so curious as to why it wasnt working. but thanks guys.

Answer (score 2):

First of, be sure to set the second parameter of `header()` to true, it is to force setting the header:

```
header('Content-Type: text/csv');
```

Give that you know the size of the download, you should:

```
header('Content-Length: '.strlen($fields));
```

Finally, be sure that `$fields` is actually a string in CSV format.

You can't print an array directly and expect the browser to automagically convert it to CSV.

Answer (score 1):

Proper MIME type is `text/csv`.  Try that.

Answer (score 0):

Try marking the `Content-type` as either `application/download` or `application/force-download`. That should force the browser to open the save dialogue.